# Using foreign_key in rails associations has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Could somebody explain me is my code correct.

I'm trying to get foreign_key option in rails associations.

I have **2** models:
**Book** and **Author**

Book db schema:

- name
- user_id

Author db schema:

- name

My models:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books, foreign_key: :user_id
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, foreign_key: :user_id
end
```

Here I don't understand why we should define **foreign_key** in both models. Is it necessarily?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have used the table and column names that Rails expects, then you do not need to explicitly define the foreign_key.  In your case, if the foreign key column was named `author_id`, then you could get by quite simply:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
end
```

However, in your case, the foreign key column is not named according to what Rails expects, so you have needed to explicitly define the foreign key column name.  That's fine, but it does make a little more work for you.

In cases where you have explicitly defined the foreign key, you should define it for both associations.  Your `has_many` association will not work without it.

In addition, you should define the inverse association:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books, foreign_key: :user_id, inverse_of: :author
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, foreign_key: :user_id, inverse_of: :books
end
```

Defining the inverse_of can cause ActiveRecord to make fewer queries, and gets rid of a few surprise behaviors.  For an explanation of inverse_of, see [Exploring the `:inverse_of` Option on Rails Model Associations](https://www.viget.com/articles/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations) by Ryan Stenberg

Comment: Okay. You mean model Author(without defined foreign_key) would look for an author_id field in table books. That's why we should explicitly define foreign_key?

Comment: @DorianG That is correct.  I've added that to the answer.

Comment: @WayneConrad thanks a lot! I discovered the effects of `custom foreign key` myself through rigorous tests before finding your answer. Now I can feel the case truly! Hopefully your other concern about the `:inverse_of` option will definitely save a lot of efforts :) wonder why this is not clearly explained in the rails guide/api :(